# How wait for other results in callback in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am creating a code that's read PDF files and transforms them into CSV. The code works already reading a file at a time. Now I'm trying to read more than one file at a time, explaining the code:

I have my bin/www which will initialize the code by command line:

```
Command: node bin/www oneArchive.pdf twoArchive.pdf

'use strict';
var Break = require('../core');

var node    = process.argv[0];
var script  = process.argv[1];
var length  = process.argv.length;
var files   = [];

if (length > 2) {
    for (var i = 2; i < length; i++) {
        files.push(process.argv[i]);
    }

    Break.extract(files);
}
```

I'm going to pass a array, regardless if is one archive, two, or three. So, i create the logic to put the filename inside files array, and send to Break.extract:

```
var Break = {

    /**
     * Responsible for extract the text from PDF, DOC or TXT files.
     *
     */
    extract: function(files) {
        Extract.init(files);
    },
};
```

I have other phases, but I need to work at the moment is the extraction phase where I send an array with the name of the file, this phase will read the text inside the file only.

My needs at this stage is to get the files that I'm sending in an array, become the same text files in an other array, them send to the next stage, which is not relevant now.

Continuing..

So, sent for the extraction phase:

```
var Extract = {
    init: function(files, callback) {
        this.files      = files;
        this.callback   = callback;

        SeparateFiles.init(files, Extract.result);
    },

    result: function(files) {        
        console.log(files);
    }
};
```

This is the most important part i think, i want separate the files and return an array in the result method with texts inside.

So:

```
SeparateFiles -> [File1.pdf, File2.pdf] -> LOGIC -> result method [Text1.pdf, Text2.pdf]
```

SeparateFiles:

```
var SeparateFiles = {
    init: function(files, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Types.read(files[i], 'pdf', callback);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm doing a looping here, which will make the Read one by one, inside the read method in Types object i have:

```
/// ALL THE LOGIC TO BREAK THE FILE

When you finish, send to callback function, which is the result method.
```

The problem here is that i'm receiving one text, them the other, and i want receive both in the same time in an array.

The problem here is the looping i think, i know how to apply the logic in two files and after send to result method, but i want apply the logic, wait for both finish and than send to result.

The read logic is very large, i cant paste here, but i have several methods and in the final i just send the text to the result method.

Comment: Seems like you are describing async operations but your code looks sync... I think you left out the most important part, the part where you read the files.

Comment: what is `Types.read`.  as @elclanrs pointed out your code is performing as if you were executing syncronous operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `callback` for `SeparateFiles.init` is being called once for each `Types.read` completion, where it should only be called after you finish processing all of the files.

In the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) package, there's a `map` function that does exactly that.

Without that you'll need to code it yourself.  Something like:

```
var SeparateFiles = {
    init: function(files, callback) {
        var result = [];  // This will be passed to the final callback
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Types.read(files[i], 'pdf', function(err, text) {
               if (err) {
                   callback(err);
                   return;
               }
               result.push(text);  // Add the Type.read output to the callback result array
               if (result.length === files.length) { // Done??
                   callback(null, result); // Invoke final callback
               }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Promises?**

If you're going for complex async operations, it might be worth looking at using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Though they're not widely supported by legacy browsers, there are lots of polyfills which can fill in those gaps.

With promises, if you want to wait for two separate asynchronous operations to finish before continuing, you would do something like the following:

```
Promise.all([async1, async2])
       .then(function() {
            //Only when both async1 and async2 have been resolved
            //(completed without failure) does this code execute
        });
```

Here's [a great article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) on JS Promises

Here's [a polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise#readme) for promises (which is actually linked in the above article).

Hope this helps!